# Multiple 'foreach' loops in one knockout JS

Tags: asp.net, knockout.js, dotnetnuke

I'll start by saying that I am working within the context of DotNetNuke7, which is essentially ASP.net based framework, and that i am fairly new to KO.

I am trying to have one ko viewmodel and have two foreach loops in it. Each loop renders an array which is part of the view model definition like so:

```
    //We build two arrays: one for the users that are in the group 
    //and one for the users that are not in the group 
    var nonGroupMembers = $.map(initialData.NonGroupUsers, function (item) { return new   Member(item); });
    var groupMembers = $.map(initialData.GroupUsers, function (item) { return new Member(item); });

    //The members we start with before we added new members 
    self.SearchTerm = ko.observable('');
    self.CircleMembers = ko.observableArray(groupMembers);
    self.NonCircleMembers = ko.observableArray(nonGroupMembers);
```

In the html context (or the asp user control) i placed the following code

```
<div id="socialDirectory" class="dnnForm dnnMemberDirectory">
    <ul id="mdMemberList" class="mdMemberList dnnClear" style="display:none" 
         data-bind="foreach: { data: NonCircleMembers, afterRender: handleAfterRender }, 
                        css: { mdMemberListVisible : Visible }, visible: HasMembers()">
        <li class="memberItem">

            <div data-bind="visible: $parent.isEven($data)">
                <%=MemberItemTemplate %>
            </div>            
            <div data-bind="visible: !$parent.isEven($data)">
                <%=MemberAlternateItemTemplate %>
            </div>            

        </li>
    </ul>  
</div>

<div class="circleDirectory"  id="circleDirectory"  >

    <ul id="cdMembersList" data-bind =" foreach: {data: CircleMembers, afterRender: handleAfterRender}">
            <li class="memberItem"> 
               <div class="mdMemberDetails">
                    <a href="" class="mdMemberImg" data-bind="attr: { title: DisplayName, href: ProfileUrl }">
                        <span><img data-bind="attr: { src: getProfilePicture(50,50), title: DisplayName }" /></span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="MdMemberInfo">
                        <li class="mdDisplayName" >
                                <a href="" title="" class="mdMemberTitle" 
                                    data-bind="attr: { title: DisplayName, href: ProfileUrl }, 
                                    event: { mouseover: $parent.showPopUp }">
                                <span data-bind="text: DisplayName"></span>
                            </a>
                        </li>  
                        <li class="mdTitle"><p><span data-bind="text: Title"></span></p></li>
                        <li class="mdLocation"><p><span data-bind="text: Location()"></span></p></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Each one of the DIVs which contain the foreach binding loop in them works perfectly well without the other. For instance, the bottom div (id= cdMembersList) will work fine but when I add the upper div with the binding markups it will stop working. The same thing happens vise verse.

Does anybody have a clue why it might happen? Can i not have 2 loops in one view model?

looking forward to solving this mystery.

thanks,
David

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I hate to say it but the answer is very simple as always. I didn't add to my view model the **Visible** property for 
     **css: { mdMemberListVisible : Visible }**

When I created a new script file I simply skipped this property. A few lessons:

1. You can run more than one loop in one view model.
2. Always check that you have all the properties defined in the view model.

Also, apparently it helps creating a question on this board since it makes you think clearly about the problem and revisit your actions. I had spent 2 hours chasing this problem before i posted my question, and then it took me 15 minutes to solve it after I posted it.